# How can I style a canvas element?

Tags: html, image, canvas, mask

I found a canvas animation and changed it to suit my needs, but because a canvas and its shapes are not a DOM elements I can't get it to style properly. [Here is my current progress](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/630082/progress.html).

If you mouse over the image the bouncing progress bar animates. If you mouse out it will bounce back. How can I style it with a background image so I can get it to look like a speedometer?

Comment: I see no "progress bar" in your Demo (Safari v5.1.2 on OS X).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing